# what best practice to add or update map key if key doesn't exists

Tags: scala

I wonder what is the best practice to add or update map key if key doesn't exists.
For instance this piece of code will throws exception.

```
val states = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
states(1) = "Alaska"
states(2) = states(2) + " A Really Big State" // throws null pointer exeption
```

Thanks

Comment: If you _have to_ use mutable map (you probably don't), just use java's `ConcurrentHashMap` ... at least, it is thread safe. It also has `putIfAbsent` and `computeIfAbsent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
val states = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
states(1) = "Alaska"
states.get(2) match {
  case Some(e) => states.update(2, e + "A really Big State")
  case None => states.put(2, "A really Big State")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To update if the entry is absent you can do:

```
states.getOrElseUpdate(2, " A Really Big State")
```

Here's an example of how it works

```
val states = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
val empty = states.get(2) // empty == None
val bigState = states.getOrElseUpdate(2, "A Really Big State") // bigState == A Really Big State
val stillBigState = states.getOrElseUpdate(2, "An even bigger state") // stillBigState == A Really Big State
```